# Does $x \ge -x$ lead to a contradiction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm little trained in inequalities and analysis but I was working through the following inequality:

$bx +5 \ge 3 $
when $b>0$

So what I did to approach this was the following:
$$(1)\space \space \space \space  bx \ge -3 \implies x\ge-\frac{3}{b}$$

Which implies further by the inequality that $$(2)\space \space \space \space  -\frac{3}{b}\le x\le\frac{3}{b}$$

Let's multiply the LHS of 1 by $b$
$$b^2x \ge -3b$$
Replacing $x$ for the inequalitiy limits of $x$ in (2) I get:
$$b^2\left(\frac{3}{b}\right)\ge -3b \implies 3b\ge-3b$$

My question is, when can $3b \ge -3b$ be true when $3b=-3b$ is not possible when $b>0$. Would the sign of inequality $\ge$ not work in this case, or am I misunderstanding it purpose?

For example $3b>-3b$ but $3b \ne -3b$ when $b>0$?

Comment: $x\geq -x$ holds if and only if $x\geq 0$.

Comment: I don't see how you get (2), for example, taking $b = 1$ it is clear that $x + 5 \geq 3$ implies $x \geq -3$, but how do you get $x \leq 3$?

Comment: @Rushy I thought that when the minus is switched between sides, the inequalities also reverse?

Comment: $$x≥-x\iff 2x≥0\iff x≥0.$$

Comment: @lonestudent Thanks for showing me this!

Comment: @Stackcans the direction of your inequality could change if $b < 0$ was a possibility, which it is not

Comment: @user190080 Out of curiosity, how would this look if $b<0$? I'm guessing something like this: $-bx \ge -3 \implies x \le \frac{3}{b}$? Thanks for the responses as they've cleared many of my doubts

Comment: @Stackcans if you have $bx>1$ and you start with basically 2 cases where $b$ is either $>0$ or $<0$, in the latter you would get $bx>1 \Leftrightarrow x<1/b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x\ge -x$ means "either $x=-x$ or $x>-x$ ", there is no  contradiction.

Comment: And does this case also hold when $ab \ge -ab$ when $b>0$?

Comment: Yes, @Stackcans; multiplying an inequality by a positive number always leaves the inequality unchanged in its direction.